# Enable/disable operator depending on a Boolean value

Tags: python, operator

I have two buttons operators, I've disabled one from the start using the below line, where `started` is False:

```
def poll(cls, context):
        return started
```

I wonder how I can enable it back when I click on another button operator which sets the bool `started` to `True`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eeeeh… where do you store that `started` variable?

Either you use a global variable here (which is not recommended, but would work) or, much more recommended, you add a new property to WindowManager class to store that bool, and retrieve it in your `poll()` func through the context parameter…